# powershell Reading & writing to multiple files

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that is an output log from a series of Oracle SQL scripts that are ran as part of a database deployment.
I want to convert this to HTML so that any errors/warnings that I define in regular expressions can be made to stand out, as this log is several MB in size.

This is all run on Windows, so I thought I’d try Powershell to do it so I’d learn something as well. I am using Powershell version 2.0 for all of this.

So far I have the following code:

```
($ifile=input file, $ofile=output file)
param($ifile, $ofile)

Set-Content $ofile `<html`>
Add-Content $ofile `<body`>

(Get-Content $ifile) | 
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "&","&amp" `
        -replace ">", "&gt;" `
        -replace "<", "&lt;" `
        -replace '\b(?!(ORA-20+|ORA-01430|ORA-00955|ORA-02260|ORA-01442|ORA-01418|ORA-01408|ORA-31003)(?=\d|\b))^ORA-[0-9]+\d?\b(.*)' , '<font color=red><b>ORAERROR-$_</b></font>' `
        -replace '((?i)PLS-+|SP2-+)(.*)', '<font color=red><b>ORAERROR-$_</b></font>' `
        -replace '((?i)ORA-20+|ORA-01430|ORA-00955|ORA-02260|ORA-01442|ORA-01418|ORA-01408|ORA-31003)(.*)','<font color=orange><b>ORAWARNING-$_</b></font>'} | 
        foreach-object {$_ + "<br>"} | 
            Add-Content $ofile

Add-Content $ofile `<`/body`>
Add-Content $ofile `<`/html`>
```

Now I want to expand it to do more and look better and I’m stuck….

Here is what I want to do:

- Output html & body tags to output file
- Output a header to output file
- For each line:

  - replace any matched regular expressions with **line of matched text**
  - If there was a match, output   (pointing to the id above) to outputfile
  - output the line (matched or not) into a temp file with a <br> at the end
    until EOF
  - cat temp file onto end of output file.

By doing this I hope to end up with an output file that looks something like this:

```
HEADER
---------------------------------
Link to error $countnumber
Link to error $countnumber
Link to error $countnumber
..
..
..
Link to error $countnumber N
----------------------------------------
The whole of the log file including tags
..
..
..
EOF
```

I'm specifically stuck around trying to do the -replace bits into the temp file but then also doing the <a href...> bits to the outputfile at the same time. It may not even be possible the way I am approaching it!!

Any help would be much appreciated.

If I am way off course with my logic and understanding of Powershell, please can you point me in the general direction and I'll go and do some more reading.....lots of reading.

Cheers
Nick

Comment: Can you show a sample of the log file you're reading?

Comment: Yes...also, please be more specific about what's not working. "stuck around trying to do the -replace bits into the temp file" is pretty vague; what exactly is going wrong--what are your results and how do they differ from the intended results?

Comment: BTW, you don't really need to pipe to **Foreach-Object**. You can just do this: `(Get-Content $ifile) -replace '&', '&amp' -replace '>', '&gt;' [etc...] | Add-Content $ofile`. I also recommend the habit of using single quotes by default, and only double-quoting when you need to use interpolation features; that helps avoid unintended results.

Comment: @AdiInbar That is good advice. I even take it one step further and generally use .NET string formatting, while single-quoting my strings. That way, I can do fancy stuff like this inside of a script cmdlet (advanced function) for logging purposes: `Write-Verbose -Message ('{0}: {1}: Something happened' -f (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd), $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName);`

Comment: You may want to look into Tee-Object as well, if you are wanting multiple outputs.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan Yes, you can use -f for fancier formatting, but what I'm driving at is the opposite--don't use fancier forms of quoting unless you actually need them. A lot of people use double quotes by default (i.e. when it doesn't matter which type) and single quotes only when "needed", because it's a habit that comes from regular writing practices. I'm saying it's a better habit in programming to default to single quotes and only use double quotes when you specifically need to interpolate something, because it helps avoid unnecessary debugging due to overlooking special characters.

Comment: @neontapir Or, if you want to add the same content to multiple files, you can just give **Add-Content** a comma-separated list of files: `[...] | Add-Content $ofile, $tempfile`. Which one is best depends of course on the specific requirements, which is why I'm waiting for the OP to provide some sample data and clarify what he's trying to accomplish, because it's vague and confusing as currently written.

Comment: @AdiInbar Yes I know that's what you were saying. I agree with you, and was simply extrapolating on that point.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for all your advice. Unfortunately I cant post the actual output as it is work related and contains stuff that I cant post.

Comment: Ah, pressed the wrong key!!! I appreciate it was a bit vague but when you have limited knowledge its difficult to be precise. But I will bear that in mind for future posts. Fortunately for me @HAL9256 gave me vurtually everything I need to do, very much appreciated, so I will use & adapt that for now. It's good to know that people were willing to help a newbie though and I really appreciate your assistance. More specifics next time though Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to do here.

- Split up your -replace routines, so you can handle the cases separately.
- Instead of outputting those replacements straight to the file, you want to output it to a variable so that you can process your whole file first to create the header. Output the header to the file, then the body of text.
- To get your links, you are looking at using named anchors See:[Links Within a Page](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm)
- To get the appropriate named anchors, you want to use a MatchEvaluator script block to:

  - Calculate the next named anchor to use.
  - Create a Header entry
  - Create the named anchor to embed, and return that to insert into the replace statement.

**One Important note:** This will **ONLY** work on PowerShell version 2.0. This will not work with PowerShell version 3.0+ because in 3.0+ script blocks can't access variables outside their scopes. See: [Undocumented changes to Powershell Scope handling v2/v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515186/undocumented-changes-to-powershell-scope-handling-v2-v3/)

But since you are using PowerShell 2.0, you can try this code:

```
#Note this will only work in PowerShell V 2.0 see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515186/undocumented-changes-to-powershell-scope-handling-v2-v3/

($ifile=input file, $ofile=output file)
param($ifile, $ofile)

Set-Content $ofile `<html`>
Add-Content $ofile `<body`>

#Define Global Variables
$Global:i = 0

#Header for the file
$Global:Header = ""

#Body for the file
$Body = ""

$ErrorMatchEval = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator] {
    #Build the Header that points to the named ancor
    $Header += "<a href=`"#$i`">$($args[0])</a><br>`n"
    #Output back the replacement with named anchor, and red bold error message
    Write-Output "<a name=`"$i`"></a><font color=red><b>ORAERROR-$($args[0])</b></font>"
    #increment anchor count variable
    $i ++;
}

$WarningMatchEval = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator] {
    #Build the Header that points to the named ancor
    $Header += "<a href=`"#$i`">$($args[0])</a><br>`n"
    #Output back the replacement with named anchor, and orange bold warning message
    Write-Output "<a name=`"$i`"></a><font color=orange><b>ORAWARNING-$($args[0])</b></font>"
    #increment anchor count variable
    $i ++;
}

(Get-Content $ifile) | 
    Foreach-Object {
        #Replace all & < >
        $_ -replace "&","&amp" `
        -replace ">", "&gt;" `
        -replace "<", "&lt;"

        #Find errors
        $_ = [regex]::Replace($_, '\b(?!(ORA-20+|ORA-01430|ORA-00955|ORA-02260|ORA-01442|ORA-01418|ORA-01408|ORA-31003)(?=\d|\b))^ORA-[0-9]+\d?\b(.*)', $ErrorMatchEval)
        $_ = [regex]::Replace($_, '((?i)PLS-+|SP2-+)(.*)', $ErrorMatchEval)

        #Find Warnings
        $_ = [regex]::Replace($_, '((?i)ORA-20+|ORA-01430|ORA-00955|ORA-02260|ORA-01442|ORA-01418|ORA-01408|ORA-31003)(.*)', $WarningMatchEval)

        #Put in line breaks, and append to body
        $Body += $_ + "<br>`n"
        }

#Add the header first
Add-Content $ofile $Header

#Add the rest of the body
Add-Content $ofile $Body

Add-Content $ofile `<`/body`>
Add-Content $ofile `<`/html`>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this @HAL9256 This works almost exactly as I wanted. I really appreciate it. You've saved me a lot of time. Now I must go away and learn more. Thanks