# Powershell: Referencing local variables from a delegate

Tags: powershell, delegates, powershell-3.0

I have the following code (simplified, this is not my actual use case):

```
$actions = @()

@(1,2,3) | ForEach-Object {
    $localCopy = $_
    $actions += {Write-Output $localCopy}
}

$actions | ForEach-Object { $_.Invoke() }
```

It outputs:

```
3
3
3
```

However, the output I want is:

```
1
2
3
```

In something like C#, assigning the *$localCopy* variable would be enough to create a new, local variable that the delegate would reference when called. However, Powershell has different scoping - I am using Powershell 3.0, so the delegate gets invoked in its own scope (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515186/undocumented-changes-to-powershell-scope-handling-v2-v3)). I tried playing with the *$local:* prefix on *$localCopy*, but that didn't work (as expected given the scoping rules).

So, if a delegate is invoked in its own scope, is this just impossible to accomplish? How can I assign a temporary variable that is available when the delegate is executed? I understand there's probably a solution to this using *NewScriptBlock*, but that just seems excessively complex to what I'd think would be a simple operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use GetNewClosure (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure(v=vs.85).aspx).  Here is an example:

```
$actions = @()
@(1,2,3) | ForEach-Object {
    $localCopy = $_
    $actions += {Write-Output $localCopy}.GetNewClosure()
}
$actions | % { $_.Invoke() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to evaluate the local variable immediately:

```
$actions = @()

@(1,2,3) | ForEach-Object {
    $localCopy = $_
    $actions += [ScriptBlock]::Create("Write-Output $localCopy")
}

$actions | ForEach-Object { $_.Invoke() }
```

Comment: This can work for some simple cases, but if the variable is a non-trivial type or even a string with spaces, this won't work very well..